# Can you use ssh for internet remotely?

Tags: wireless, ssh, internet

I am getting very interested in ssh. I believe I have configured the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file properly. What I want to be able to do is use the internet through ssh, and print to my wireless printer. I found this youtube video on how to use putty to connect to the internet remotely:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAqqho5yR88. However, I continue to get this error message when I go to the Tunnel button in putty. [image: putty]

Is there something that I could be doing differently? I put the ip address of the computer I want to connect to, and I have added a port but no luck so far.  Again, thank you all for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Here is the official [port fortwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/OpenSSH/PortForwarding) help.